# Unable to add Items to cart

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django and react to build a simple checkout system. When I click on the add to cart button I get `404 page not found` but the click event is supposed to add item to the cart instead of rendering a page. I'm not sure whether my function for the onclick event is accurate in the programme below. I'm finding great difficulty trying to figure out why I'm not able to add Items to the cart by clicking on the cart button using `onClick` event. The url on the console is pointing to the actual url containing the id of the element I'm trying to add. I can see the the error in both the browser console and Django server on the terminal. I don't know whether the error is with the react app or Django.

```
urls.py (Django)
path('add-to-cart/', add_to_cart_view.as_view(), name='add-to-cart'),
```

```
The react component 

const AddToCartURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const ProductDetails = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const id = props.match.params.id;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(`${ProductDetailURL}/product/${id}`);
                setProduct(res.data);
                console.log(res.data)
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [props.match.params.id]);

    const handleAddToCartURL = (id) =>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await axios.post(`${AddToCartURL}/add-to-cart/${id}`);
                setProduct(res.data);
                console.log(res.data)
            }
            catch (err) {

            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }

    return(
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} m={4}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                <Grid item xs={9}>
                    <Item>
                       <img src={product.image} alt="" />
                       <div>
                           <p>{product.description}</p>
                           <p>{product.label}</p>
                           <p>{product.price}</p>

                       </div>
                       <button color='primary' onClick={() => handleAddToCartURL(product.id)}>
                            <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                        </button>  
                    </Item>                  
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <Item>Similar Products</Item>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
    
      </Box>
    )
}


export default ProductDetails
```

And the Django programme for add to cart is:

```
class add_to_cart_view(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.data.get('id', None)
        if id is None:
            return Response({"message": "Invalid request. Ensure ypu have added added products to the cart"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)

        order_product_qs = product.objects.get_or_create(
            product=product,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        
        if order_product_qs.exists():
            order_product = order_product_qs.first()
            order_product.quantity += 1
            order_product.save()
        else:
            order_product = product.objects.create(
                product=product,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )
            
    
        order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
        if order_qs.exists():
            order = order_qs[0]
            if not order.products.filter(product__id=order_product_qs.id).exists():
                order.products.add(order_product)
                return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.products.add(order_product)
            return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't have to declare the fetchData function within the handleAddToCartURL function, make the handleAddToCartURL function async and run the try/catch block directly within it.  As for the 404, sounds like your urls between front end and backend don't match (you haven't posted what the value of the AddToCartUrl to cart variable is or your django urls.py file)

Comment: Thanks a lot @coot3 for the correction on `handleAddToCart`. As for the `404 page not found` please look through the question again. I have added the value of `AddToCartURL` as well as the backend url I'm fetching the data from.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating.  To send query parameters to add_to_cart you need to use a question mark instead of a slash:

```
`${AddToCartURL}/add-to-cart?${id}`
```

You can access the parameters  within add_to_cart_view using:

```
request.query_params
```

DRF recommends using this instead of djangos request.GET (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params)

Comment: Thank you. I changed my code to include the `?` in ``${AddToCartURL}/add-to-cart?${id}` but I get another error: `401 unauthorized` error. As for the `request.query_params`, I'm sending a post request from ad-to-cart view in django. I'm not using `get` request

Comment: youll have to look into drf authentication (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/), but putting permission_classes = [] under class add_to_Cart_view should allow anyone to access the view without authentication